# Read-only access to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I need to give business analysts a web tool to query row data in a SQL Server production DB (I know it's not a good idea, but big boss said so ...). How do I make sure they can only run SQL SELECTs or LINQ Selects, but not modify anything? My plan initially was to create a user with read-only permission, but it turns out the DBA is on vacation for a month ...

So to make it more clear - I'm looking for a way to create ASP.NET page(s) that would expose all tables in a given DB for reading, but not writing.

Comment: Does "the DBA is on vacation for a month" mean you can't do anything at all at the SQL Server level? Or does it just mean you are asking here because you can't discuss it with your DBA?

Comment: Hi Aaron, your great answers on SQL Server related questions here have helped me so many times ;) I can't do anything on the servers (there is an emergency support, but it is very expensive).

Comment: Also how does your DBA get a month of vacation at a time? Especially when there is obviously ongoing database work. At the very least there should be a backup plan (at least one person should be able to cover his/her responsibilities), but I'd also like to find out how I can take a month off like that...

Comment: This is Spar .. err .. Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Build the queries on the webserver.
- Create a new sql instance and copy the data across.
- export the data to something else.

there are probably a lot more options, a new sql instance with a copy of the live data is going to be your best bet.

If it was me though I'd just tell "Big Boss" the dba is on holiday and you don't have the necessary permissions on the database to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for ASP.NET Dynamic Data web site [with read only access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837196%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, never used Dynamic Data before. How can the users query the DB?

Comment: They don't query data. They browse tables exposed in ASP.NET tables.